# How to Add Sequence to Names(If Duplicated) Stored in a List

Tags: java, arraylist

Given the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;

public class FileNameSeq {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //List containing duplicate names 
        List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("JAVA", "JAVA", "JAVA", "CPP", "JAVA", "CPP" ,"C"));
        ArrayList<String> filenameList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; al.size() > 0;) {
            int freq = Collections.frequency(al, al.get(i));
            String fileName = al.get(i);
            filenameList.add(fileName.concat("-").concat("" + freq));
            al.remove(i); /* removing the element */
        }

        System.out.println(filenameList);
    }

}
```

I have developed this piece of code to generate sequence if there are similar names stored in the list, then first occurrence of the name should be appended with `"-1"` ,second with `"-2"` and so on till `"-N"`and if there are no duplicate then name should remains the same. While running the program i am getting the following output

```
[JAVA-4, JAVA-3, JAVA-2, CPP-2, JAVA-1, CPP-1, C-1]
```

but Output should be like

```
[JAVA-4, JAVA-3, JAVA-2, CPP-2, JAVA-1, CPP-1, C]
```

`C` should not have `"-1"` appended to it.

What changes should I need to make to produce the later output?

Comment: If I read your specification, shouldn't the output be **JAVA-1, JAVA-2, JAVA-3, CPP-1, JAVA-4, CPP-2, C**?

Comment: Yeah that would also do the job

Comment: So @Swapnil , you can have a look to my answer. The implementation is also preferable I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to test there was originally only one occurrence in your collection.

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

        //List containing duplicate names 
        List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("JAVA", "JAVA", "JAVA", "CPP", "JAVA", "CPP" ,"C"));
        ArrayList<String> filenameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        //Creates a copy of the collection, which will remain unchanged
        List<String> alCopy = new ArrayList<String>(al);
        for (int i = 0; al.size() > 0;) {
            String fileName = al.get(i);
            int freq = Collections.frequency(al,fileName);
            boolean toConcat = freq != 1;
            if(!toConcat){
                //checks if there was actually only one occurrence of filename 
                //or if it is only the last one
                toConcat =( Collections.frequency(alCopy,fileName) != 1);
            }
            if(toConcat){
                filenameList.add(fileName.concat("-").concat("" + freq));
                //Why not filenameList.add(fileName + "-" + freq)); ??
            } else {
                filenameList.add(fileName);
            }
            al.remove(i); /* removing the element */
        }

        System.out.println(filenameList);
}
```

Please note that this code will generate the output you mentioned in your question

> [JAVA-4, JAVA-3, JAVA-2, CPP-2, JAVA-1, CPP-1, C]

If you want the output I suggested :

> [JAVA-1, JAVA-2, JAVA-3, CPP-1, JAVA-4, CPP-2, C]

You can use the following code that uses a map to count each occurrence of a filename.

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

        //List containing duplicate names 
        List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("JAVA", "JAVA", "JAVA", "CPP", "JAVA", "CPP" ,"C"));
        ArrayList<String> filenameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<String, Integer>counters = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for(String fileName : al){
            Integer count = counters.get(fileName);
            boolean toConcat = true;
            if(count == null){
                //First occurence. Is it the only one?
                count = 0;
                if(Collections.frequency(al,fileName) == 1){
                    toConcat = false;
                }
            }
            count += 1;
            counters.put(fileName, count);
            if(toConcat){
                filenameList.add(fileName.concat("-").concat("" + count));
                //Why not filenameList.add(fileName + "-" + count)); ??
            } else {
                filenameList.add(fileName);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(filenameList);
}
```

Note that in this case we don't have to modify the original collection, which is much cleaner.

**EDIT**

As others mentioned in their answer the first solution is not very effective because `Collection.frequency` always scans the whole collection. In addition to that, removing elements from the original collection is not very clean in my opinion.

We can thus use a code similar to the last example here above to generate the first output (`[JAVA-4, JAVA-3, JAVA-2, CPP-2, JAVA-1, CPP-1, C-1]`).
It is also based on a map of counters but in this case we put the number of occurrences per filename and we decrease the counter on each occurrence instead of starting from 0 and increasing the counter.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //List containing duplicate names 
    List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("JAVA", "JAVA", "JAVA", "CPP", "JAVA", "CPP" ,"C"));
    ArrayList<String> filenameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Map<String, Integer>counters = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for(String fileName : al){
        Integer count = counters.get(fileName);
        boolean toConcat = true;
        if(count == null){
            //First occurrence. 
            //The number appended to the filename is the number of occurrences 
            count = Collections.frequency(al,fileName);
            //Is it the only one? If so we won't append anything to the filename
            //beware count is an Integer, not an int so '==' doesn't work 
            if(count.equals(1)){
                toConcat = false;
            }
        } else {
            //we can now decrease the counter
            count -= 1;
        }
        counters.put(fileName, count);
        if(toConcat){
            filenameList.add(fileName.concat("-").concat("" + count));
            //Why not filenameList.add(fileName + "-" + count)); ??
        } else {
            filenameList.add(fileName);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(filenameList);
}
```

Comment: could we produce the output as [JAVA-4, JAVA-3, JAVA-2, CPP-2, JAVA-1, CPP-1, C] with the first approach you mentioned without removing items from the list but preserving the order?

Comment: yeah that did the job

Answer (score 0):

The last element in your collection has 1 frequency, and you can use condition to remove it from the end.

```
filenameList.add(fileName.concat(al.size() == 1?"":("-" + freq)));
```

Comment: it didn't work if i provide list as Arrays.asList("JAVA", "JAVA", "JAVA", "CPP", "JAVA", "CPP" ,"C","ORACLE","NODE.JS","ORACLE","NODE.JS","NODE.JS")

Comment: I have make an example to show you an idea, how did you provide the list?

Comment: Is this a different question? `"C"` should be the last element of the list to get the results you expect. Could you provide a junit testcase for the code?

Comment: this is actually test data, real list have more than 1000 entries

Comment: You didn't answer my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Roman C's and Prerak Sola's answers are fine but it wont exactly match the expected output. Their output would be . . .

[JAVA-4, JAVA-3, JAVA-2, CPP-2, **JAVA**, **CPP**, C]

Since you are removing from your source list, when you get to a single item, you don't have a way of telling if that item was duplicate or not. You need to keep some sort of map or state for each item.

I would do the following instead . . . (This is if you really really want to have items "JAVA-1"/"CPP-1")

1) Make map `Map<String,Integer>`

2) Populate map with key being list item (e.g. "JAVA", "CPP") and value being the count of the list item (e.g. 4 for "JAVA", 2 for "CPP").

3) Iterate through the entry's. If the value == 1, then add the key to the output list. If count > 1, then add `ITEM + "-" + i` for `i = 1...count` to the output list

Here's some psuedocode

```
List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> list = {"JAVA","JAVA","JAVA","CPP","JAVA","CPP", "C"};

Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for(String item : list) {
   if(map.contains(item)) {
      map.put(item, map.get(item)+1);
   } else {
      map.put(item, 1);
   }
}

for(Entry<String,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if(entry.value == 1) {
       output.add(entry.key);
    } else if(entry.value > 1) {
       for(int i = 1; i <= entry.value; i++) {
           output.add(entry.key + "-" + i);
       }
    }
}
```

Note - This should output the correct items but the order will not be preserved

Answer (score 0):

If you want lower it's time complexity from polynomial to linear you can use this implementation utilizing `HashMap`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //List containing duplicate names 
    List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("JAVA", "JAVA", "JAVA", "CPP", "JAVA", "CPP", "C"));
    ArrayList<String> filenameList = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    while (!al.isEmpty()) {
        String fileName = al.remove(al.size() - 1);
        Integer count = map.get(fileName);
        if (count == null && Collections.frequency(al, fileName) > 0) {
            map.put(fileName, 1);
            fileName = addSequence(fileName, 1);
        }
        if(count != null) {
            count++;
            map.put(fileName, count);
            fileName = addSequence(fileName, count);
        }
        filenameList.add(0, fileName);
    }
    System.out.println(filenameList);
}

protected static String addSequence(String fileName, int freq) {
    return fileName.concat("-").concat("" + freq);
}
```

And its output:
`[JAVA-4, JAVA-3, JAVA-2, CPP-2, JAVA-1, CPP-1, C]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I could come up with using streams from Java 8.

1. Group the items together, into a map, with frequency counts greater than 1
2. Apply reverse sequence count to items that are in the map

Code sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // List containing duplicate names 
    List<String> al = new ArrayList(Arrays
            .asList("JAVA", "JAVA", "JAVA", "CPP", "JAVA", "CPP", "C"));
    // Group items together that have a frequency greater than 1
    Map<String, Long> groupings = al
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors
                    .groupingBy(Object::toString, Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(item -> item.getValue() > 1)
            .collect(Collectors
                    .toMap(item -> item.getKey(), item -> item.getValue()));

    // Apply reverse sequence to duplicate items
    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
        String item = al.get(i);
        Long count = groupings.get(item); 
        if (count != null) {
            al.set(i, item.concat("-" + count));
            groupings.put(item, count - 1);
        }
    }

    // Display results
    System.out.println(al);
}
```

Results:

```
[JAVA-4, JAVA-3, JAVA-2, CPP-2, JAVA-1, CPP-1, C]
```

Comment: Doesn't this implementation suffer from the fact that you have to pass up to `n` times, where `n` is the number of elements of `al`, over the stream of `al`. In each pass you apply a filter operation which again passes over the complete list. Thus, the overall complexity is `O(n^2)`. But the problem is solvable in `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `Collections.frequency` in every iteration does not give you a really efficient algorithm. A better approach would be to count how often each element appears in the sequence of strings and then assign the numbers. An example algorithm could look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //List containing duplicate names
    List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("JAVA", "JAVA", "JAVA", "CPP", "JAVA", "CPP", "C"));
    ArrayList<String> filenameList = new ArrayList<String>();

    Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for(String element: al) {
        if(counts.containsKey(element)) {
            counts.put(element, counts.get(element) + 1);
        } else {
            counts.put(element, 1);
        }
    }

    // remove all elements which have a count of 1
    for(Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> it = counts.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = it.next();

        if(entry.getValue() == 1) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }

    for(String element: al) {
        if(counts.containsKey(element)) {
            int counter = counts.get(element);
            counts.put(element, counter - 1);

            filenameList.add(element.concat("-").concat("" + counter));
        } else {
            filenameList.add(element);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(filenameList);
}
```

Output:

```
[JAVA-4, JAVA-3, JAVA-2, CPP-2, JAVA-1, CPP-1, C]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which makes use of some Java8 features (mainly because I wanted to try something, they're not required). It's basically your approach, but with an additional map of word counts from the original list to check if there once were multiple occurrences of that word.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class FileNameSeq {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // List containing duplicate names
    List<String> al = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("JAVA", "JAVA", "JAVA", "CPP",
        "JAVA", "CPP", "C"));
    List<String> filenameList = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<String, Long> wordCounts = al.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Object::toString, Collectors.counting()));
    Iterator<String> it = al.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      String fileName = it.next();
      if (wordCounts.get(fileName) > 1) {
        fileName = fileName.concat("-" + Collections.frequency(al, fileName));
      }
      filenameList.add(fileName);
      it.remove();
    }

    System.out.println(filenameList);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[JAVA-4, JAVA-3, JAVA-2, CPP-2, JAVA-1, CPP-1, C]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SortingAndAddingData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mapEffiecientWay();
    }

    private static void mapEffiecientWay() {
        List<EmpFile> listEmp = prepareList();
        // Yu can omit it if you dont want sorting.
        Set<EmpFile> sortedEmpFile = new TreeSet<>((o1, o2) -> o2.getFileId().compareTo(o1.getFileId()));
        Map<String, List<EmpFile>> mapDuplicate = new HashMap<>();
        List<EmpFile> finalEmpFile = new ArrayList<>();

        sortedEmpFile.addAll(listEmp);
        sortedEmpFile.stream().forEach(file -> {
            List<EmpFile> fileNameList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (null != file.getFileName()) {
                String combinedNameForDuplicate = file.getFileName();
                if (null != mapDuplicate.get(combinedNameForDuplicate)) {
                    fileNameList = mapDuplicate.get(combinedNameForDuplicate);
                    file.setDuplicate(fileNameList.size());
                }
                fileNameList.add(file);
                mapDuplicate.put(combinedNameForDuplicate, fileNameList);
            } else {
                finalEmpFile.add(file);
            }
        });

        mapDuplicate.values().stream().forEach(finalEmpFile::addAll);

    }

    private static List<EmpFile> prepareList() {
        EmpFile e1 = new EmpFile(); e1.setFileId("A"); e1.setFileName("A-1");
        EmpFile e2 = new EmpFile(); e2.setFileId("B"); e2.setFileName("A-1");
        EmpFile e3 = new EmpFile(); e3.setFileId("C"); e3.setFileName("A-2");
        EmpFile e4 = new EmpFile(); e4.setFileId("D"); e4.setFileName("A-1");

        List<EmpFile> listEmp = new ArrayList<>();
        listEmp.add(e4); listEmp.add(e2); listEmp.add(e1); listEmp.add(e3);
        return listEmp;
    }
}

class EmpFile {
    private String fileId; private String fileName; private int duplicate;
   // Setters and getters

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Make your `for` loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; al.size() > 0;) {
    int freq = Collections.frequency(al, al.get(i));
    String fileName = al.get(i);

    if(freq != 1)
        filenameList.add(fileName.concat("-").concat("" + freq));
    else
        filenameList.add(fileName);

    al.remove(i); /* removing the element */
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this only append a number to a filename which appears exactly once? Thus, the output would be `[JAVA, JAVA, JAVA, CPP, JAVA-1, CPP-1, C-1]`. I guess that is not the intended behaviour.

Comment: I see two defects in your answer : you obviously tested `freq == 1` instead of `freq == 1` and even that shouldn't work because it would NEVER write the `-1` suffix.

Comment: This does not produce the desired results.  It produces [JAVA-4, JAVA-3, JAVA-2, CPP-2, JAVA, CPP, C].  The last JAVA & CPP are missing their "-1".

Comment: That was silly of me. Corrected the `==` mistake. For the second one, @user2615897 's answer would do the work, it showing `-1` is a priority for the repeating elements.